# Html to Word long document

Tags: html, ms-word

I can create an extensive word document using html including a cover page, header & footer, page numbers etc.
But my problem is; when my document is too long (like 100 pages or more) and I open the doc with Word 2003:

- the document can be loaded and I can see the cover page.
- but when I try to scroll down a little bit to examine the report, Word starts a long lasting process ( I don't know what it is) and does not respond.
- if the doc is about 60 pages, the process lasts about 5 min. And then I can navigate through the document.

I have tried the following:

- Disabled Spelling and Grammar check
- Disabled auto-save

Is there anyone with a similar experience? I am creating the document with html and a few vml tags embedded in the document. What can be the cause of this unresponsive behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Word is not created for handling large documents. There are several places where behavior is not O(n log n) (with n length of the document). You need to at least disable page numbering.

If you really want to find out: create some test cases and find out:

- start with a plain text only, nothing fancy at all, generate a 100 pages and see if the problem persists.
- step by step add features until the problem surfaces (fastest is to halve the feature difference).
- it is likely that there are more features than just one leading to these performance problems, so you have to be careful with the application of Newton's method

And when you know, tell us.

Comment: I gave it a try. But still no luck. Long documents seem to lock Word 2003. I can open the document in a few seconds with Word 2007. But I have to use Word 2003.